# Droidparts: how to get to autocreated column names in m2m table?

Tags: droidparts

community.

I am just start to use droidparts. 
As I got it is cool library. But it has poor documentation, and no comments in code itself.
I am interested in getting elegant approach to use it.

Well suppose, i've created tables **items**, **users**, **items2users** as ***many-to-many*** concept.
Tables **items** and **users** are trivial. Table **items2users** is

```
@Table(name="items2users")
public class ItemsToUsers extends Entity {
    @Column
    public Item item;
    @Column
    public User user;
}
```

So if I need to get answer if my User has Item I do something like that in UserManager class:

```
public boolean hasItem(Item item) {
    Select<ItemsToUsers> select = select().columns(ID).where({HERE_I_NEED_COLUMN_NAME}, Is.EQUAL, user.id);   
}
```

Droidparts made table with fields '***item_id***' and '***user_id***'. As I understand **HERE_I_NEED_FIELD_NAME** must be '***user_id***'. As I realize it is automatic naming model for this situation? 
Well is there some elegant technique to achive this names or I should construct them manually getting '***user***' and '***_***' and '***id***'?

Answer (score 0):

By default the column name will be field name + _id, e.g. `item_id` & `user_id` in your case. That can be altered through annotation, e.g. `@Column(name="some_other_name")`.